# How to design a part to fit exactly onto an existing 3D model?

Tags: modeling

I have been trying to fix the front fender part of a vintage pedal car for a friend. It is a piece that is broken, and I would like to design and 3D print a part that fits perfectly to the broken part, kind of like what was done [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/A-sandstone-block-built-from-lego-blending-real-o/)... The .stl file from a 3D scan of the broken fender is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0j3WGD5eyXjVHlBOUtFSjNkWW8/edit?usp=sharing) and was I hoping to get some advice or help. Please note that the complete part is symmetrical. Thank you

[image: image of broken part]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would do:

Start by importing the file and aligning it with the grid. Aligning with the x-y-z axes will make tranformations easier.
[image: Align the model with the grid]

Next, go into Edit mode and select the good half of the model by pressing `b` and clicking/dragging your cursor . Preferably, you should do this after smoothing out the scanning imperfections so that you don't have to clean each side of the model independently.
[image: Select the good half of the model]

Use `Shift+d` to duplicate the selected vertices and `p` to separate them from the original mesh. The new mesh is no longer closed, and you will need to close off the opened edge of the mesh before performing any boolean operations. Select the outer ring of vertices, and use `Shift+F` to fill the empty space.
[image: Fill the empty edge]

Using a combination of mirror transformations, rotating, and moving, place the closed mesh in the desired position on the other side of the model. You might have to move the new mesh down slightly or decrease its scale by a tiny amount, so that none of the new mesh's faces hide faces along the top of the original mesh.
[image: Place the new mesh in its proper position]

The new mesh is now overlapping the broken edge of the original mesh and needs to be trimmed to fit.
[image: The new mesh overlaps the broken edge]

In Object mode, select the new mesh (blue) first, hold `Shift`, and then select the original mesh (red). Press `w`, and click `Difference`. Blender will subtract the original mesh from the new mesh and introduce a third mesh containing the difference. The third mesh (colored green here) should closely fit the original mesh's broken edges.
[image: Fitted mesh]

[image: Animation]

I can add a .blend file later today if it will help. Cleaning and accurately scaling the mesh will probably be the most challenging part of this project.

Comment: Welcome to the site, nice first answer :) May I ask why you are using 2.49?

Comment: @gandalf3 I just haven't taken the time to learn the new interface. It's probably about time for me to make the jump.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the scan, why not just take the scan of the fender and mirror the good side and merge it in?

I gave it a go importing into blender and into sketchup. The STL looks okay, but I have some questions:

1) Is the fender component symmetrical? I'm seeing tabs on either side that don't match on the other side. If you have a photo of the original part that was scanned and a photo of how it looks on the original car, that would help determine how to match it up.

2) What is the scale of the fender?

Working with it in Blender, one can smooth out the bumpiness of the scan. Another reason one would want to see what the original looked like. :)

Comment: The fender component is symmetrical, as you can see in the image I just attached to the original post. It has newspaper on it in an attempt to create a better scan. I could not locate an image of the original part... I definitely like the idea of mirroring the good side, and have tried a bit. Also please help me with merging the part. I have tried, but have been unable to figure it out. I was thinking maybe a boolean modifier, but I am not sure...

Comment: Looks like nth0007's answer and mesh blends is right on. (Sorry, much belated answer)